# How to set a new form to a subform within a subform? [accdb]

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, subform

So , I have changed our app from a 'mbd' to a 'accdb' and some of the declarations don't work the way that they are supposed to.

This line of code works on the 'mbd' file , but it doesn't on 'accdb'

```
Dim subformachart As Form
Set subformachart = Form![subChart].Form!subChartSpace.Form
```

where:

- form -> is the main form
- subChart -> is the first subform
- subChartSpace -> is the 2nd subform

This is what I have tried after researching on some documentation, but it doesn't work (also the documentation was always talking about controls and other proprieties , but never about the .Form propriety)

```
Dim subformachart As Form
Set subformachart = Me!subChart.Form!subChartSpace.Form

This doesn't work.
```

Also , if I want to access just the first subform as in

```
Set subformachart = Me!subChart.Form
```

it works just fine, but I can't find a way to access the 2nd subform as in the mbd example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mix `subform control name` and `form name` or maybe it is a problem with the scope of the code?

I tested the following constellation:

- A main form `frmMain` containing a subform control named `subChart`, containing a form named `frmSub`.
- The sub form `frmSub` containing a subform control named `subChartSpace`, containing a form named `frmSubSub`.
- The sub sub form named `frmSubSub`.

The following code, placed in the `onclick` procedure of a button on the `frmMain`, executes well:

```vb
'Using Me:
MsgBox Me.subChart.Form.subChartSpace.Form.Name

'Using Form:
MsgBox Form.subChart.Form.subChartSpace.Form.Name

'Set the form in a local variable, using your syntax example:
Dim subformachart As Form
Set subformachart = Form![subChart].Form!subChartSpace.Form
MsgBox subformachart.Name
```

If you call code from outside the main form, lets say from a standard module, then you must use the `forms` collection to reference the main form first:

```
MsgBox Forms("frmMain").subChart.Form.subChartSpace.Form.Name
```

I can't see any other reason for your problem.